# Brightness adjustment not working on a Samsung NP300e5za0pin

Tags: 12.04, brightness, samsung

Recently installed Ubuntu 12.04 on my Samsung NP300e5za0pin laptop . Brightness function is not fully functioning, and it will not bring down below 70% when I press the <kbd>FN+</kbd>+Brighness.

Brightness automatically becomes 100% and then again loss of battery.

Please give some suggestion to solve the problem !!

Answer (score 2):

I got another samsung laptop. Try to add/change this line in your `/etc/default/grub` file and run update-grub and restart afterwards. It fixed my problem with the brightness control.

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_osi="
```

However, battery life is still terrible under Ubuntu .. only 2 hours instead of 4 hours. If anybody has a fix for that, it would be appreciated.

Comment: If you have optimus graphics, installing bumblebee does wonders for your battery life! See here http://vxlabs.com/2012/05/01/review-of-ubuntu-linux-12-04-on-the-samsung-np300v3a-core-i5-nvidia-optimus-laptop/ for my account.